# KeyError in String Formatting of Raw Input

Tags: python

```
name = raw_input("kemal ")
quest = raw_input("To learn python ")
color = raw_input("Blue i guess ")
print "Ah, so your name is {name}, your quest is {quest}, " \
"and your favorite color is {color}.".format(name, quest, color)
```

I can't find what's wrong with this code. Python says " KeyError: 'name' " when I run it.

Comment: I would suggest doing some formatting to help people answer your question.

Comment: Format it in a readable way (multiple lines) and show the full traceback of the error

Comment: To use named interpolation, you need keyword arguments, not just positional arguments: `"Hello {planet}!".format(planet="world")`.

Comment: Kemal, if you are wondering why your question attracted so many downvotes, it is because of your title which was not descriptive of the problem; and bad formatting of your original question. Welcome to this super helpful community, and enjoy it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use named arguments to use their name in the template:

```
"...{name}....".format(name=name, quest=quest, color=color)
```

If you use positional arguments, then you need to use index in template:

```
"...{0}...".format(name, quest, color)
```

Documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must edit your string formatting to this:

```
print "Ah, so your name is {}, your quest is {},"\
"and your favorite color is {}.".format(name, quest, color)
```

Secondly, you are using the raw_input incorrectly.

You shouldn't key in what the input is, you should ask it from the user. So the full correct code looks like this:

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name")
quest = raw_input("Enter your quest")
color = raw_input("Enter your color")
print "Ah, so your name is {}, your quest is {},"\
"and your favorite color is {}.".format(name, quest, color)
```

Key in your name, quest and color when prompted, it will print out correctly.